# How to store images from dall E 2 API into mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm creating a web application that accepts a user's prompt and then uses the dall E 2 api to generate an image. The issue that I'm running into is that once the image is generated. I want to store it in MongoDB so that I can retrieve it later to be displayed on a web gallery. My problem is that I cant use the URL of the image because it expires after an hour. So is there a way to store it without the URL into mongodb

So im using node.js and javascript. I have a couple of ideas to try but dont know if they work. I want to see if anyone else has had this issue and how did they get through it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not recomended to store images in the database, either it is sql or no sql

Instead, share the image in a public path, and store the image url in the database so the url points to your image in your public path

Another alternative that could be useful for you is using cloudinary which provides an easy api to start working: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_integration

I hope this suggestion was useful

Comment: Makes sense. Would you have an idea on how to download the dall e 2 api image. The way I'm think of it is to store it on a local folder and then set the sec attribute to the path

Comment: If you are using express, say in your project you have a public folder, so you can store the image for example in /public/img/img1.jpg so the path would be '/img/img1.jpg' <- Notice the value has to be stored in the database. You can use axios, or maybe another lightweight library to download the image

Comment: so im using axios and fs and im getting this error message. Error saving image: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404. do you know how to trouble shoot. I know it means that the webpage cant be found but the url in the dom works fine.

Comment: I tried to generate an image and test on my own to download with axios but the api said me 'Billing hard limit has been reached'

Comment: Hmm. Sounds like you reached the limit of free request and have to pay. That's unfortunate. I'll keep trying and playing around with it. I think it might be a CORS issue. Thanks for your assistance. I have a better idea on what to do. Will update once i have a solution